# Directory Size to MySQL Table

Tags: php

I use this function to get directory size and store total on MySQL with Cronjob

```
function CalcDirectorySize($DirectoryPath) {
$Size = 0;

$Dir = opendir($DirectoryPath);

if (!$Dir)
    return -1;

while (($File = readdir($Dir)) !== false) {

    // Skip file pointers
    if ($File[0] == '.') continue; 

    // Go recursive down, or add the file size
    if (is_dir($DirectoryPath . $File))            
        $Size += CalcDirectorySize($DirectoryPath . $File . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    else 
        $Size += filesize($DirectoryPath . $File);        
}

closedir($Dir);

return $Size;
}
```

On large directory > 30 GB and hundreds of files, is very slow an load 100% CPU

Exist an equivalent function to get directory size without load CPU 100% and most quickly?

TKS HID

Comment: OS functions such as `du` would be more efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get the size this way:

```
chdir ($DirectoryPath);
$bytes = intval(preg_replace('/[\D]+/','',system('du',$result)));
```

This get the details of the size of directory and sub-directories.

```
system('du',$result)
```

This eliminates all characters except numeric digits

```
preg_replace('/[\D]+/','',
```

This converts the string of returned digits to an integer value.

```
intval()
```